# How to use SUMIF function when it comes to drop down menu variables?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I'm sorry if this seems like a silly question but u was hoping someone could help me out.

I'm making a rather mediocre sheet to keep track of my hybrid working rota, for me and my colleagues.

We have a simple calendar layout, with a drop-down menu on each day to say whether we've been working from the office, at home, or on holiday.

And I need to have a total number of all the relevant days to then input it into our system at work for HR use etc.
Up to this point, we've been counting the days manually, but I was hoping to automate the process to make our lives easier.

So I wanted to know if there is a way where I can use the SUMIF function - or a function similar to it, that will give me the total number of "Holiday", "Office", and "Home" days in the month based on what's in the table :)

I attach a link to a copy of our simple layout which shows the idea :)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14h46qMtJcH1VSE1aR6H-fGXPCPCmjwMnYb_Qi2-qjY4/edit?usp=drivesdk

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

*if you wish to calculate for each rota separately, then enter this in `Cell_J9` and then drag it down*

```js
=countif(B$7:H$15,I9)
```

*this **alternate** formula auto-calculates the whole thing in one go (as shown in screenshot)*

```js
=let(Σ,tocol(B6:H15,1),
     Λ,filter(Σ,istext(Σ)),
     Γ,unique(Λ),
     {Γ,index(countif(Λ,Γ))})
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!! I hope you understand that to me and my team you're a magical genius! :) <3